# Resize Images for Categories when showing on the frontend

Tags: category

below is code i am using to add custome image attirbute to magento category

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_image', array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'My Image',
    'input'         => 'image',
    'backend'       => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'required'      => false,
    'sort_order'    => 99,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group'         => 'General Information'
));
```

and below code to show that images on frontend:

```
  echo $imagepathidentifier =  Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getData('identifier_image')->resize(100);
```

now above code shows error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in    [...] listcustomtops.phtml on line 39 –
```

what to do resize images and then show to user..

Comment: Which error is shown?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function resize() on a non-object in D:\pathher\catalog\product\listcustomtops.phtml on line 39

Answer (score 2):

If my assumption is right,probably you have confused with `resize()` of magento `catalog/image` Helper class method, it can be applied for product image only. if you want to use that one see this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48369/how-to-use-catalog-image-helper-class-features-and-magento-cache-for-non-produ).